# Why Does Selenium Add a Space to Attribute?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to retrieve the style attribute on Google.com of the element `.//*[@id='hplogo']`. The expected value is `padding-top:109px;` (without a space) but the actual value Selenium returns is `padding-top: 109px;` (with a space between  `:` and `109`).

I don't understand why Selenium adds a space if in `HTML` there is no space.

I know I could remove the space manually but I want to know if there's a way to prevent the space from appearing in the first place (mainly bec there are other attribute values with a real space and I do not want to remove the space from the values that actually have a space).

So when does Selenium decide to add a space in middle of an attribute and how can it be prevented?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the way the method `getAttribute()` is implemented which adds the space.
According to [Selenium's Java API documentation](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) for the `getAttribute()` method:

> The "style" attribute is converted as best can be to a text
>   representation with a trailing semi-colon.

So it's safe to assume the additional space is added by the underlying selenium code. I don't think you can do anything to avoid it other than removing the space yourself.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that this behavior is implemented only with the "style" attribute and no other attributes? I still don't understand why they do this.. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can safely assume it's only with the style attribute. I tried looking under the hood to find how the `getAttribute()` is implemented, but didn't find anything meaningful.